# Flutter: Firebase getting unexpected large number of reads... and how to avoid reads on console

Tags: flutter, firebase, flutter-listview

my homepage uses 3 different listview.builder to display data from futures

```
 getFuture() async {   
          setState(() {
            Future1 = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Posts").orderBy(sortBy, descending: descending).limit(20).get();
            Future2 =  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Posts").orderBy("source", descending: descending).limit(10).get();
            Future3 =  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Posts").orderBy("date_sort", descending: descending).limit(10).get();
          });
      }
```

i also implemented lazyloading for **Future1**:

```
  getDocumentsNext(String sortBy, bool descending) async {
    var lastVisible = collectionState!.docs[collectionState!.docs.length-1];
    print('listDocument legnth: ${collectionState!.size} last: $lastVisible');
    collection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Posts').orderBy(sortBy, descending: descending).startAfterDocument(lastVisible).limit(25).get();
    fetchDocuments(collection!);
  }

  fetchDocuments(Future collection){
    collection.then((value) {
      collectionState = value;
      value.docs.forEach((element) {
        setState(() {
          listDocument.add((element.data()));
        });
      });
    });
  }
```

so only **Future1** will add more doc to the list upon scrolling vertically, while **Future2 & Future3** will remain unchanged and display 10 items only.

however when i try to scroll the listview.builder, for example 5 times which i got 5 x 25 = 125 of docs loaded ... but my firebase console is showing 1k+ of reads, sometimes can go up to 4k-5k reads if i scroll around 10 times...

how can this possible if the size of my entire dataset is just 3k of docs, and i just loaded less than 500 of doc but getting 1k+ of reads sometimes even more than the size of my dataset ?

==========================================================

EDIT: how to avoid extra reads on firebase console ?

Comment: You will need to consider that usage of the Firestore console incurs reads as well.  And if you leave the console open on a busy collection, it will accrue more reads as it reflects the contents in real time.

Comment: if i have an extremely large dataset, like 10 millions of docs... whenever i use the console that would incur 10mil of reads ?? how can i maintain the console if thats the case ...

Comment: No, that would make the console unusable.  Notice how the data fills lazily in as you scroll down the list of documents.

Comment: is there any suggested way to avoid reads on console?

Comment: There is only one way: don't open it.